# How to make to make sequential async calls and pass data to a sibling component properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, fetch, async.js

I'm trying to build a hackernews clone as a practice to reactjs. Here I'm trying to build this only with react and later I'm going to build this with Redux.
This is my component structure.

```
--main
  |--menubar
  |--articles
```

Here is the [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/zxmj47rm3x) for the project.

I'm having two issues here.

1.)
Here I'm passing data through state and props.I'm calling the API in `componentDidMount` method on `menubar` component and pass it to the `articles` component through `main` component. But it doesn't render the list when it receives the data through `props` in `componentWillReceiveProps` method. To render it I have to click `News` (which has no connection with fetching data, it's just printing a log) which will recall the API method. How can I render the data in `this.state.articleList` when the data is received through props and set the data.

2.)
In the API call, I have defined to get first 20 posts only. But when I click `news`, I'm getting random number of (<20) posts rendered in each time. Why is that ? As the API call is same, shouldn't it render same amount of(20) posts ? Why it differ ?

Is the both issues because of Asynchronous methods ? If so how can I solve them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually its because of async, i edited it using the [async library](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map) edited the **fetchdata()** and added **getItems()**.

The advantage of using map is that it will return an array of results itself so we need not maintain an array.

```
var async = require("async");

fetchdata() {
fetch("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    this.setState({ storyList: data }, () => {
      this.getItems(this.state.storyList);
    });
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(`Error fetching data : ${err}`));
  }


getItems(storyList) {
    async.mapLimit(storyList, 10,
      function(item, callback) {
        console.log(item);
        fetch(`https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${item}.json`)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {

            //pass the data here
            callback(null, data);
          });
      },
      function(err, dataArray) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
        } else {

          //dataArray will contain an array of results from map
          this.props.getData(dataArray);
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked and solved the 1st problem I'm having. But even though it receives given no of articles and pass the data to the `articles` component correctly the `article` component doesn't render the article list. It renders only after I trigger an event like clicking `news` link (which is completely independent from this). Why's that ? Is that the same reason (because of async) ?

And Is there any downside of using something like this ? Performance wise ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Hi after getting the data inside getItems binding the data to callback getData as follows

getItems(storyList) {
    var story_list = [];
    async.mapLimit(
        storyList,
        10,
        ((item, callback) =>{
            console.log(item);
            fetch(`https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${item}.json`)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                    story_list.push(data);
                    this.props.getData(story_list);
                });
        }),
            ((err) =>{
            if (err) {
                console.error(err.message);
            } else {
                this.props.getData(story_list);
            }
        })
    );
}
```

Comment: This gives an error saying `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'props' of undefined`

So I call `this.props.getData(stroy_list)` after `async.mapLimit` method. It solves the issue but still it don't render on startup (even though `article` component receive data)

Comment: Yea, Calling `this.props.getData(story_list)` gives the above mentioned error. Anyhow solved the issue by calling it after `async.mapLimit` function

Comment: @ThidasaParanavitharana are you call the getData() after the callback() ? could you update your https://codesandbox.io/s/qk5qzqzolq so that i can check and let you know